# zmq/zeromq recv_multipart hangs on large data

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm trying to modify a zeromq [example](http://zderadicka.eu/long-running-taks-in-web-appdjango/) for processing background task and get it working. In particular, I have a xpub/xsub sockets setup, and a client would subscribe to the publisher to receive progress updates and results from the worker.

**worker_server.py**

```
proxy = zmq.devices.ThreadDevice(zmq.QUEUE, zmq.XSUB, zmq.XPUB)
proxy.bind_in('tcp://127.0.0.1:5002')
proxy.bind_out('tcp://127.0.0.1:5003')
proxy.start()
```

**client.py**

```
ctx = zmq.Context()
socket = server.create_socket(ctx, 'sub')
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
poller = zmq.Poller()
print 'polling'
poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
ready = dict(poller.poll())
print 'polling done'
if ready and ready.has_key(socket):
    job_id, code, result = socket.recv_multipart()

return {'status': code, 'data': result}
```

So far, the code works for small messages, however when the worker tries to publish the task results which is large, 35393030 bytes, client does not receive the message and code hangs at `ready = dict(poller.poll())` Now, I just started learning to use zmq, but isn't send_multipart supposed to chunk the messages? what is causing the client to not receive results

**worker.py**

```
def worker(logger_name, method, **task_kwargs):
    job_id = os.getpid()

    ctx = zmq.Context()
    socket = create_socket(ctx, 'pub')
    time.sleep(1)

    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    sh = WSLoggingHandler(socket, job_id)
    fh = logging.FileHandler(filename=os.path.join(tmp_folder, 'classifier.log.txt'), encoding='utf-8')

    logger.addHandler(ch)
    logger.addHandler(sh)
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    modules_arr = method.split('.')
    m = __import__(".".join(modules_arr[:-1]), globals(), locals(), -1)
    fn = getattr(m, modules_arr[-1])

    try:
        results = fn(**task_kwargs)
        print 'size of data file %s' %len(results)
        data = [
            str(job_id),
            SUCCESS_CODE,
            results
        ]
        tracker = socket.send_multipart(data)

        print 'sent!!!'
    except Exception, e:
        print traceback.format_exc()
        socket.send_multipart((
            str(job_id),
            ERROR_CODE,
            str(e)
        ))
    finally:
        socket.close()
```

**EDIT:**
Tried manually splitting up the results into smaller chunks but haven had success.

```
    results = fn(**task_kwargs)
    print 'size of data file %s' %len(results)
    data = [
        str(job_id),
        SUCCESS_CODE,
    ] + [results[i: i + 20] for i in xrange(0, len(results), 20)]
    print 'list size %s' %len(data)
    tracker = socket.send_multipart(data)

    print 'sent!!!'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the pyzmq documentation:
https://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/api/zmq.html#zmq.Socket.send_multipart

> msg_parts : iterable
>
> A sequence of objects to send as a multipart message. Each element can be any sendable object (Frame, bytes, buffer-providers)

The message doesn't get chunked automatically, each element in the iterable you pass in is the chunk. So the way you have it set up, all of your result data will be one chunk. You'll need to use an iterator that chunks your results into an appropriate size.

Comment: tried your suggestions but no improvements. see updates.